# STM32L152 Bare Metal Rust without HAL

Tags: assembly, rust, arm, bare-metal

I'm currently in the 11th grade and did some programming with assembler in class. For fun I sat down and tried to use Rust instead of assembler. I managed to get an LED to light up but the blinking still doesn't work. The assembly code works and the first write_volatile works and turns on the LED. But after the write volatile nothing happens I think it goes into an endless loop. I wanted to ask if anyone can give me some tips on how to make this code work better or get it working. I tried to do it with only unsafe and write_volatile.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::arch::asm;
use core::panic::PanicInfo;
use core::ptr::write_volatile;

#[no_mangle]
#[link_section = ".text._start"]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let led_base: u32 = 0x40020000;
    let led_state = led_base | 0x14;

    unsafe {
        asm!(
        "ldr r1, =0x40023800",
        "ldr r0, =0x00008007",
        "str r0, [r1, #0x1C]", // Enable GPIO: A, B, C
        "ldr r1, =0x40020000",
        "ldr r0, =0xA8000400",
        "str r0, [r1, #0x00]", // Set LED as output
        /*"ldr r0, =0x20",
        "ldr r1, =0x40020000",
        "str r0, [r1, #0x14]"*/ // Turn LED on
        );

        loop {
            write_volatile(led_state as *mut u32, 1 << 5); // Turn LED on

            for _ in 0..65000 { // Wait
                asm!("nop");
            }

            write_volatile(led_state as *mut u32, 0x00); // Turn LED off

            for _ in 0..65000 { // Wait
                asm!("nop");
            }
        }
    }
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

I also uploaded the project to a Github repository: https://github.com/HttpRafa/school/tree/asm-j0

I already wrote the Blink program in full assembler and it worked. So all addresses and offsets should be correct.

```
.word 0x20000400            //Anfang Stackpionter -> SP
.word 0x080000ed            //reset_handler: Programmadresse nach reset
.space 0xe4             //Reservierter Platz für Interrupt-Vektoren

//###### Registerdefinitionen: Namen, Basisadresse/Offset ######
.equ RCC,0x40023800         //Basisadresse: System-Clock
.equ AHBENR,0x1C            //Offset:

.equ GPIOA,0x40020000       //Basisadresse GPIOA
.equ MODER,0x00             //Offset: MODER "Mode Register"
.equ ODR,0x14               //Offset: ODR "Output Data Register"
 

.global _start              //für Linker wichtig: Definition, an welcher Adresse das Programm anfängt
_start: 

ldr r1, =RCC            //GPIOA,B,C aktivieren (7:...111)
ldr r0, =0x00008007     //
str r0, [r1,AHBENR]     

ldr r1, =0x40020000
ldr r0, =0xA8000400
str r0, [r1, #0x00]     // Set LED as output

main:
  bl led_on
  bl wait
  bl led_off
  bl wait
b main                      //Endlosschleife Hauptprogramm- Sprung zu main

wait:
  mov r3, #65000
  mov r4, #0
  for_0:
    add r4, r4, #1
    cmp r4, r3
    bne for_0
  bx r14

led_on:
  ldr r0, =0x20
  ldr r1, =0x40020000
  str r0, [r1, #0x14]
  bx r14

led_off:
  ldr r0, =0x00
  ldr r1, =0x40020000
  str r0, [r1, #0x14]
  bx r14`
```

Comment: Hello RafaDev! To improve this question, the relevant rust code should be shown here, not just as a link to github. The reasoning is that links to to other websites tend to go bad over the years, we want this question (and answers) to still be useful years from now.

Comment: Have you looked at what asm the Rust compiles to?  Or single-stepped the Rust in a debugger, at source level or asm level?  Since you already know the key parts of the asm (stores to certain addresses), you can look for those in the Rust.  (Enable some optimization if loads/stores of locals on the stack is cluttering up the compiler-generated asm too much.)  Anyway, "doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description for a [mcve], like do you get a compiler error, or does it run in an infinite loop with the LED on or off? Or crash at run-time?  Anyway, use a debugger to find more detail.

Comment: In your `main.rs`, you have an `asm!("")` statement with just code, no clobbers to tell the compiler which registers you modify.  That's undefined behaviour; it doesn't parse your asm to figure out registers for you.  The compiler-generated asm probably also uses the same registers you did, perhaps for loop counters.  Rust inline asm is pretty similar in design (template / operands / clobbers) to GNU C inline asm; see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Comment: instead of the asm nop you can have it call a function in asm or in some other file that is outside the compile domain, and have that function just return.  it burns more clocks but looks/smells a bit cleaner for a count loop that just burns some time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it running. I removed the asm macro to avoid conflicts and I changed the compiler from debug to release.
Here is my new code:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::arch::asm;
use core::panic::PanicInfo;
use core::ptr::write_volatile;

#[no_mangle]
#[link_section = ".text._start"]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let led_base_address: u32 = 0x40020000;

    unsafe {
        /*asm!(
        "ldr r1, =0x40023800",
        "ldr r0, =0x00008007",
        "str r0, [r1, #0x1C]", // Enable GPIO: A, B, C
        "ldr r1, =0x40020000",
        "ldr r0, =0xA8000400",
        "str r0, [r1, #0x00]", // Set LED as output
        "ldr r0, =0x20",
        "ldr r1, =0x40020000",
        "str r0, [r1, #0x14]" // Turn LED on
        );*/

        write_volatile((0x40023800 | 0x1C) as *mut u32, 0x00008007); // Enable GPIO: A, B, C
        write_volatile(led_base_address as *mut u32, 0xA8000400); // Set LED as output

        loop {
            write_volatile((led_base_address | 0x14) as *mut u32, 1 << 5); // Turn LED on

            for _ in 0..65000 { // Wait
                asm!("nop");
            }

            write_volatile((led_base_address | 0x14) as *mut u32, 0x00); // Turn LED off

            for _ in 0..65000 { // Wait
                asm!("nop");
            }
        }
    }
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```